# Which Messaging System to be used?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I would like to transfer data from one db system to any other db systems. which messaging system(Kafka, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ.....likewise) would be better to achieve this with much throughput and performance.

Comment: Questions [asking for recommendations like this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are off-topic: _"4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the answer for this type of questions is "it depends"

You probably could find many information on the internet about comparison between these message brokers,

as far as I can share from our experience and knowledge, Kafka and its ecosystem tools like kafka connect , introducing your requested behavior with source connectors and sink connectors using kafka in the middle,

Kafka connect is a framework which allows adding plugin called connectors

Sink connectors- reads from kafka and send that data to target system

Source  connector- read from source store and write to kafka

Using kafka connect is "no code", calling rest api to set configuration of the connectors.

Kafka is distributed system that supports very high throughout with low latency. It supports near real time streaming of data.

Kafka is highly adopted by the biggest companies around the world.

There are many tools and vendors that support your use case, they vary in price and support, it depends from which sources you need to take data and to which targets you wish to write, should it be cdc/near real time or "batch" copy